# Endless Waiting for a runner to pick up this job in github enterprise

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-runners

EDIT: My repo resides in github enterprise

I have a very basic github workflow action as below:
All it does is to run a powershell script as mentioned in [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-a-script-using-powershell-core).

```yaml
name: First Github Action
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  first-job:
    name: First Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Display the path
        run: echo ${env:PATH}
        shell: pwsh
```

Unfortunately, it just keeps waiting for the runner to pick up. Below is the message it is being displayed.

```
Requested labels: ubuntu-latest
Job defined at: {myUserName}/{repoName}/.github/workflows/{myFileName}.yml@refs/heads/main
Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
```

EDIT: I created another public repo and ran the action. It is still waiting. [image]

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot share my public repo as it is an enterprise github repo owned by the company I work in.

Comment: Is the repo private or public? If it's private, you will not be able to run GitHub Actions unless you pay for a license.

Comment: It was initially private. I changed the repository visibility it to public and that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running this on GitHub Cloud (or github.com):

- GitHub Actions is only free for *public* repositories, otherwise you have to pay for a license
- Switching the repo's visibility from from `private` to `public` may not cause the workflow that is stuck to be picked up. You will likely need to cancel it and queue a new one.
- Make sure your workflows are located in `.github/workflows` folder.

Assuming you are running this on GitHub Enterprise Cloud (GHEC):

- You need to make sure that your admin has Actions enabled
- You need to make sure that your admin has Actions allowed for repositories not owned by an organization

Assuming you are running this on GitHub Enterprise Server (GHES):

- You need to make sure that your admin has Actions enabled
- You need to make sure that your admin has Actions allowed for repositories not owned by an organization
- You **will not** be able to use GitHub hosted runners as you have in your YAML file
- You will need to use a self-hosted runner and your GitHub admin can provide you the details of what you  need to use.

The workflow you have in your question does in fact work:
https://github.com/tjc-actions-demo/simple-actions

The issue is going to be either permissions related or configuration related. Depending on your environment, you will need to troubleshoot based on my suggestions above.

Comment: I created another public repo in github enterprise. It still does the same thing. Unfortunately, I cannot share the link due to the company policies. Glad, that this is working. I will have to check with my company's enterprise github admin. I wish if I could find what configuration is missing in my repository...

Comment: If you are running this on GitHub Enterprise then that changes everything. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it in my question. I will edit the question for future reference.